# CGBitmapContextGetData result difference between iOS 3.2 and iOS 4.2

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, core-graphics

I am having problem with iOS 3.2, the same code works fine on iOS 4.2, but with the 3.2, 
CGBitmapContextGetData return nil

my code:

```
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(
                                                 NULL,
                                                 image.size.width,
                                                 image.size.height,
                                                 8,
                                                 image.size.width * 4,
                                                 CGImageGetColorSpace(image.CGImage),
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast
                                                 );

    if (context != NULL))   {

        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, image.size.width, image.size.height), image.CGImage);

        UInt32 *contextData = CGBitmapContextGetData( context );
}
```

contextData is nil when running on iOS 3.2, and returns the right value when running on iOS 4.2

Any one can explain why the result is different, and how to solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before iOS4 you had to explicity allocate memory yourself, from the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html)

> data
>
> pointer to the destination in
>   memory where the drawing is to be
>   rendered. The size of this memory
>   block should be at least
>   (bytesPerRow*height) bytes. In iOS 4.0
>   and later, and Mac OS X v10.6 and
>   later, you can pass NULL if you want
>   Quartz to allocate memory for the
>   bitmap. This frees you from managing
>   your own memory, which reduces memory
>   leak issues.

So you should do something like

```
unsigned char* dataPtr = (unsigned char*)malloc(image.size.height*image.size.width*4)
```

use that i.s.o. of NULL as your first parameter, and `free()` it at an appropriate time.